# How to do only 2 recursive calls in Prolog?

Tags: recursion, prolog, predicate

```
isTallerThan2(X,Y) :- tallerThan(X,Y).
isTallerThan2(X,Y) :- tallerThan(X,Z), isTallerThan2(Z,Y).
```

Where I want to find where someone is taller than 2 people.

If I have lots of relations where person X is taller than person Y like this `tallerThan(X,Y)`and if person b is taller than person a and person c is taller than person b... then I want to find all persons c but stop there and not find persons d,e,f... etc.

Comment: I don't understand what this means

Comment: ok so it is the number of arguments. Well it is meant to be arity 2 because there is another condition which I have not mentioned here, because I am asking a more general q.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have your database of tallerThan/2 facts, **and** you trust it (that is, tallerThan/2 is a [DAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph)), you can write your rule as simple as

```erlang
isTallerThan2(X,_Y) :- tallerThan(X,A),tallerThan(X,B),A\==B.
```

As per your comment, the second argument isn't used, so better to write like

```
isTallerThan2(X) :- tallerThan(X,A),tallerThan(X,B),A\==B.
isTallerThan2(X,_Y) :- isTallerThan2(X).
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not interested in the smaller Persons, you need to store only the larger person. There are two ways to build it: one is to hardcode two relations, the other one is to recursively code it with a counter variable.

Version one: `Z` is taller than `Y`, `Y` is taller than someone.

```
tallerThan2(Z):- 
    tallerThan(Y,_), 
    tallerThan(Z,Y).
```

For the fact base

```
tallerThan(marge, homer).
tallerThan(homer, bart).
tallerThan(bart, lisa).
tallerThan(lisa, maggie).
tallerThan(abe, maggie).
tallerThan(marge, abe).
```

the output is

```
?- tallerThan2(P).
P = marge ;
P = homer ;
P = bart ;
P = marge ;
false.
```

The second way is to count the number of relations. You know of person `Y` that he or she is taller as at least `NN` people. If person `Z` is taller than `Y` then `Z` is taller than at least `N = NN+1` people.

```
taller(Y,1) :- 
    tallerThan(Y,_).
taller(Z,N) :- 
    tallerThan(Z,Y), 
    taller(Y,NN),
    N is NN+1.
```

Now the test:

```
?- taller(P,2).
P = marge ;
P = homer ;
P = bart ;
P = marge ;
false.
```

Is the same. `marge` appears twice in the list since she is taller than `homer` and taller than `abe`; both are taller than `maggie`.